# replacement or equivalent material for toroid core inductor

Tags: inductor

hi is there any way i can replace toroid core from the circuit?.

there is this circuit which requires a toroid core inductor to function. a toroid core AL=25 with 6 turns of wire. for i know i can get the inductance value required to it from this formula, n=1000[sqrt(L/AL)] . and make an air coil inductor out of that inductance value. but i am not sure if it would really work as toroid cores do since the author of the circuit says the circuit wont work without toroid core.

and also, if an air core will be use with a very thin magnetic wire (AWG 30), can i use stick glue around the coil to support the coil?.

toroids here in our local electronic stores are not available thats why i cant provide it in my circuit.. any help with this would be much appreciated. thanks.

[image]

Comment: What circuit are you referring to?

Comment: oh sorry for that, but i have added already the schematic of the circuit i was referring. the one with which in parallel with the C2. hope you can help.thanks

Comment: Need to know what it is you're doing if we're going to be helpful. It could be that the inductor just won't fit where it needs to without a toroidal core.

Comment: the circuit is for simple RF transmission (wireless). the schematic is the receiver circuit.

Comment: the aim is that, i need to switch the LED on/off on the receiver part using the button placed on the transmitter circuit. (that is i need to build a two separate circuit, a receiver and a transmitter.) i have to switch the LED on/off wirelessly.

Comment: What RF frequency is this supposed to work on ? The inductor on the transistors collector is not coupled to the inductor at the emitter right ? Then maybe a ready made inductor would be easier. Do pay attention to the highest frequency at which it will work at though. Especially the "collector inductor" as that is a resonant tank, you need high Q.

Comment: That circuit is wrong. Where did you come across it? R4 is connected to the wrong point as far as I can see.

Comment: Yuh, actually the inductor in the circuit requires a fixed inductor as what the author of the circuit said so. The problem is that, I couldn’t find or buy a fixed inductor here in our local electronics store.  That’s why I decided to just substitute all the inductors to an air core inductor. Each of which is calculated according to its inductance value.

Comment: i am bit aware of the differences between fixed and toroid core inductor and air inductors, but it’s just that I don’t have any idea as to how and what could I replace to these required inductors. I even came up to use the E-core in replacement for toroid core?. But I am not sure with that.

Comment: The RF is supposed to work on 27MHz.
Any suggestions as to how this circuit works without fixed inductor and toroid core?

Answer (score 1):

Amidon's [FT-114-67](http://www.amidoncorp.com/ft-114-67/) has a A<sub>L</sub> of 25 and is good up to about 50MHz. It's a bit on the large side for 6 turns, but that's nothing a hot glue gun can't fix (no pun intended).